# What are the best ways to search for a given word (or words) in text

Tags: java, string, search, twitter, match

I am dealing with text processing where I have to find the number of tweets that mentioned any given word(s).For instance:

```
tweet 1: I had an egg for breakfast this morning
tweet 2: This is the book that I'll give to you tomorrow morning
tweet 3: I went there yesterday morning but you were not home. Did you go to her house this morning?
given word: this morning
```

For the example above, the frequency should be two, since there are only two tweets (tweet 1 and 3) that mention the given word in the exact way as it is given. 
I am afraid if my current implementation is inefficient (in some ways) and maybe there are the better ways to do this. What I've done so far is firstly, I try to get all the tweet that contain the given word(s).

```
public int getDF(String term) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        int frequency = 0;
        File[] paths = f.listFiles();
        for(File f:paths){
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line;
            String[] termTokens = term.split(" ");
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                if(line.toLowerCase().contains(term)){
                    if(termTokens.length > 1){ //just for multi-word
                        if(getDFUtil(line.toLowerCase(), term.toLowerCase()))
                            frequency++;
                    }else
                        frequency++;
                }
            }
        }
        return frequency;
    }
```

For a given multi-word, I called the function getDFUtil to check if the tweet is really contains the word in the given order.

```
public boolean getDFUtil(String tweet, String term){
        String[] tweetTokens = tweet.split(" ");
        String[] termTokens = term.split(" ");
        int chosenIndex = 0;
        int nextIndex = 0;
        if(termTokens.length > 1){
            for(int j=0;j<termTokens.length;j++){
                for(int i=0;i<tweetTokens.length;i++){
                    if(termTokens[j].equals(tweetTokens[i]) && j==0){
                        chosenIndex = i;
                        nextIndex = i;
                    }else if(termTokens[j].equals(tweetTokens[i])){
                        nextIndex = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(nextIndex - chosenIndex == termTokens.length - 1)
                return true;
        }else if(tweet.contains(term))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Yet, like I've mentioned earlier, I wonder (and it should be) if there are a better or simpler yet powerful way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use regular expressions(regex) for this task (If you don't know what it is, it is really worth to learn how to use it). Instead of checking every word in line if match with searched word, you can use regex to match line with given word or phrase at once. Try this small app:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int frequency = 0;
        String term = "this morning";
        File tweets = new File(//path to file Tweets.txt);
        String regex = "(?i).*"+term+".*";
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tweets));
            String line;

            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                if(line.matches(regex)){
                    frequency++;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(frequency);
    }
}
```

The `Tweets.txt` contain tweets from your example above. In short words - app count number of times given regex match with lines from file. I think you can easily implement something similar in your app.
`String.match()` method return true, only if whole string match with given regex, so in this case it is constructed this way:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode as I see you used toLowerCase()
  method, with it case doesn't metter in matching,
- `.*` - match anything in this line
- `term` - exact word or phrase you are looking for
- `.*` - match anything in this line

You can check [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/pT8aK1/2) how this particular regular expression works with your tweets.

Comment: Cool, It works and obviously a way simpler and better than mine. +1 for the link for the Regex. Ya, I will start learn more about regex as it is very important in text processing. Thank you again